# Nginx reverse proxy for multiple dotnet apps

Tags: nginx, asp.net-mvc

I have a virtual server hosted out in the cloud running ubuntu 22.04, registered to one of my domains (myapp.com).  I also have another domain (mycompany.com) and have pointed it to myapp.com in the dns entry, so that my nginx server gets traffic for both domains.

In my config file I have a single listen 80 that redirects to https like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

and then I have two ssl blocks, one for mycompany.com and one for myapp.com, myapp uses port 5000 and mycompany uses port 5005:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name www.myapp.com myapp.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
    }
}
```

and then for mycompany:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name www.mycompany.com mycompany.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:5005/;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
    }
}
```

I have two dotnet services running, with `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:5000` and `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:5005` for myapp and mycompany services respectively.

But when I go to [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com) the browser address bar correctly reflects the https redirect, but the page is renderd as if I have gone to [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com).

The dotnet app for mycompany includes the call to run on the appropriate port:

```
app.Urls.Add("http://*:5005");
```

Anyone know what might be happening?

Here is the line from the error log file:

```
2023/10/10 19:58:50 [error] 79200#79200: *21 connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: myipathome,
server: www.myapp.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico",
host: "www.mycompany.com", referrer: "https://www.mycompany.com/"
```

Comment: This was frustrating. I was trying to use a single certificate (which I made for both mycompany.com and myapp.com with certbot) for both sites.   But the handshake would see mycompany.com as myapp.com and so nginx would redirect to myapp.  I just created a new certificate for mycompany.com and everything works.  Just leaving this here in case someone else finds themselves in the same position.

Comment: There's a whole catalog of issues both with your config and your question. What does "have pointed it to" mean? Why is there no servername in the first config? Clearly the config presented in the other server blocks is incomplete - and the missing stuff is very relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I was trying to complicate this, but with separate certificates for the two sites everything works.

I have a  conf for each site in the sites-enabled directory, that look like this:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5010/;
            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

My other take away from this is that the upstream block is not necessary for what I am doing.  Originally I had the proxy pass to `http://dotnet` and then an upstream block which I think is just for load balancing.  Because I am a single server I don't need this.  I did not find this explicitly explained (or if it was I did not understand) so was really confused about how to work that in with multiple dotnet sites running on a single server.